# Numpy nd array as object for suppression of warning on "Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences ..."

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on the creation of a list of numpy nd-array. More precisely each numpy nd-array is created by stacking two 2 dimensional array by means the following function

```
    def concatBBofFrame(self, bb, frame_P, frame_A):
        r = np.stack([frame_P[bb[0]:bb[2], bb[1]:bb[3],0], frame_A[bb[0]:bb[2], bb[1]:bb[3],0]], axis=-1)
        return r
```

and it is then appended to a list.

The bb parameter change every time the `concatBBofFrame` function is called raising the following morning when I try to save the list with `np.save(datasetFile, dataset, allow_pickle=True)` do to the fact that the dimension change element by element.

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

I tried to modify the function as:

```
    def concatBBofFrame(self, bb, frame_R, frame_P, frame_A):
        r = np.stack([   np.array(frame_P[bb[0]:bb[2], bb[1]:bb[3],0],dtype=object), np.array(frame_A[bb[0]:bb[2], bb[1]:bb[3],0],dtype=object)], axis=-1)
        return r
```

I also tried with:

```
    def concatBBofFrame(self, bb, frame_R, frame_P, frame_A):
        r = np.stack([frame_P[bb[0]:bb[2], bb[1]:bb[3],0], frame_A[bb[0]:bb[2], bb[1]:bb[3],0]], axis=-1)
        r = r.astype('object')
        r = np.asanyarray(r)
        return r
```

But I was not able to avoid the warning.

Can you help me?

Comment: `np.save` saves an array.  The warning is raised when it makes an array from your list.  Do the conversion first yourself.

Comment: `np.array(dataset)` produces this warning.  `arr = np.array(dataset, object)` creates the array without the warning.